# Issue with styling child element on mouseover with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the style of the `<ul>` element when moving my mouse over the parent `<li>` element, but I can't get it to work.  I think the issue lies within the way I selected the child element since it holds an "undefined" value.

I have also tried just selecting the element by the class name but it didn't work either.

Here's the code:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".parent").on("mouseover", updatetop);

});


function updatetop() {
  var c_child = $(this).children("ul");
  c_child.style.visibility = "visible";
  c_child.style.border = "1px solid black";

}
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
}

.parent ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="parent">
  <a href="#">PARENT</a>

  <ul class="p_child">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>

</li>
```

Comment: Any reason you don't just do this with CSS?

Comment: Why you aren't using the css `:hover` pseudo class, like: `.parent:hover ul {…}`

Comment: When already using jQuery why not stick with it? jQuery has a build-in function to handle css changes: [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: And, your HTML doesn't include a `<ul>` element to contain the top-level `<li>` element.

Comment: @empiric Because JQuery is JavaScript and that means executing code in the JS runtime. If you can accomplish the same task without having to parse and execute that JS and instead just rely on the CSS rendering engine, the code becomes simpler and, often, faster.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I was not referring to JS vs. CSS, I was referring to the mixup between using a jQuery object with plain javascript. That's where his error is coming from.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I agree with you on the advantage of just using CSS for this

Comment: This is just an example. The reason i'm not using css for this is because i'm trying to do something else that requires javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `children()` method returns a jQuery collection, not a DOM object.

You can use jQuery's [**css()**](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method to do the styling:

```
var c_child = $(this).children("ul");
c_child.css({
  visibility: 'visible',
  border: '1px solid black'
});
```

**Snippet:**

```js
$(function() {
  function updatetop() {
    var c_child = $(this).children("ul");
    c_child.css({
      visibility: 'visible',
      border: '1px solid black'
    });
  }

  $(".parent").on("mouseover", updatetop);
});
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
}

.parent ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="parent">
  <a href="#">PARENT</a>

  <ul class="p_child">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
```

A more typical way to do this would be using CSS [**`:hover`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover):

```
.parent:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

That way, you won't need to add a `mouseout` event.

**Snippet:**

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
}

.parent ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.parent:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="parent">
  <a href="#">PARENT</a>

  <ul class="p_child">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add to your css

```
.parent:hover ul {
     visibility: visible;
     border: inherit;
}
```

You don't have to use jQuery for this.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can easily do this with help of CSS.

```
li.parent:hover ul {background-color:#333}
```

Let me know if you want it through jquery.